# JavaScript Calling Object Syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I need to know why this isn't working. My Javascript code accesses a variable in an object. But it appears not to be working, partly because I can't figure out the syntax.

```
    var obj = {
        size:"small",
        big:false,
        thing:true
    }

    alert(obj[size]);
```

I'm just not sure if I got the syntax right…

Comment: you are accessing a **property** of that object

Comment: also, the question is tagged with `node`, and `alert` isn't available in `node`. Use `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference object values either by:

```
obj["size"]
```

or

```
obj.size
```

However, there is an exception. For instance, if you have following object with a number key: (Note: key is still a string even if it's defined this way):

```
var obj = {
   1: true
};
```

You can retrieve it's value only by using: `obj["1"]`

Hence, using  `obj.1` will cause a syntax error.

Therefore, your code works if you change it to e.g.: `alert(obj["size"]);` but I prefer to use `console.log(obj["size"]);` for debugging. At least, if you are playing with node.js as your tags indicates.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This will work here.

```
obj.size //returns small
```

OR

```
obj["size"] //returns small
```

OR

```
var my_var = "size"
obj[my_var]  //returns small
```

Comment: Exactly.  When you do `obj[size]` it's trying to use the value of a variable called "size" as an index into the object (which is a potentially useful thing to do, but not what you want here).